# regression using lm with excluding

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, linearmodels

I am solving a question related to my course. the question is:

*Run linear model using training data with “Florence” as outcome variable, while using “Gender”, “FirstPurch”, and “all book categories” as predictors and give the summary of the model. Can you specify the significant predictors?*

I have already created the training data.

here is my attempt:

```
reg= lm(Florence~.-c(Seq.,ID.,M,R, F), data = train.df)
```

I decided to remove those variables. see the table for details:

[image]

Let me know why I cannot use -c(name of the columns)

Comment: Simply because the formula syntax for `lm()` in R doesn't allow for it.

Comment: But what if you have 19 variables to enter. it takes time to enter all of them by using +. Thank you for commenting.

Comment: You could first use `dplyr::select()` to create a reduced copy of the data frame (which allows for those kinds of shortcuts), and then use `y ~ .`.

Comment: or use `setdiff(names(df), c("..."))` + `reformulate()`